# compatibility of cucumber jvm and apache ant

Tags: java, ant, cucumber-jvm, jbehave

I am exploring an open source project. As of now, its using Jbehave and Ant. But I want to replace the usage of JBehave with Cucumber JVM. I would like to know if cucumber JVM is compatible with Apache ANT and if it is, how can i replace the usage of JBehave with cucumber JVM in same project?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use cucumber-jvm with Ant by using the JUnit runner.  Cucumber-jvm tests are then executed just like other JUnit tests.

For example, here is a simple JUnit test that will execute feature files on your classpath:

```java
package com.example.cuke;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = "json:target/report.json")
public class RunCukeTest {
}
```

You can then execute this test after having compiled it by using the following in your `build.xml`:

```xml
  <target name="test-cuke">
    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no">
      <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
      <test name="com.example.cuke.RunCukeTest"
            haltonfailure="no" todir="${report.dir}">
        <formatter type="plain" />
        <formatter type="xml" />
      </test>
    </junit>
  </target>
```

You will need to ensure the feature files as well as the step definition are on the classpath `test.classpath`.  Once they are, cucumber-jvm will take care of the rest.